# Orchard CMS with windows server 2012 r2 showing HTTP 500 - page can not displayed

Tags: iis-8, windows-server, orchardcms-1.8

I have configure orchard 1.8 with IIS 8 using windows platform installer on Windows Server 2012 r2

but showing me Http 500 page can not be displayed.. not loading the orchard CMS setup page.

I have given full permission with orchard in IIS as per mentioned steps online. but still not succeed. please help me on it.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Check the StaticFileModule is in IIS, something like this happened to me too in Window 8.1 and running on IIS Local. 
but for the looks of it you might be missing more config stuff. Check your Windows Server IIS and make sure you have everything you need enabled and install. StaticFileModule was not installed in IIS in Windows 8.1.